# How to put the WordPress blog into theme

Tags: posts, theme-development, blog, blog-page

So, I am making my own theme, and I want to know if there is a way to put your WordPress blog into a page?

P.S. My theme is set up with a "template" where it looks like this:

```
<?php
include("header.html");
if($_GET['page'] == "media") {
    include("media.html");
} else if($_GET['page'] == "contact") {
    include("contact.html");
} else {
    include("home.html");
}
include("footer.html");
?>
```

Comment: create home.php in your root, it will be picked by default as the blog post index

Comment: @DavidLee so you are saying that it automatically posts it there w/o any code?

Comment: You will need to copy what you have in 'index.php' is this a theme you made? or you made a copy of another theme? this is helpful [Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

Comment: @DavidLee I made my own

Comment: Using `include` will not take advantage of the wordpress features, try checking how the default wordpress theme is made, `index.php` its the basic page.

Comment: @DavidLee Is there a place I can find out about default wordpress themes?

Comment: The Default theme is the one that comes with WordPress, the code its commented, try this resource too [Theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/)